# Changes in scope variable not updating DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I came across this angularJs issue where a change in an array is not updating the DOM, even though there is a binding in place.

I have tried everything from using $scope.$apply, $scope.$evalAsync and also tried using vm instead of $scope.

AngularJs code:

```
app.controller("controller", function ($scope){
    $scope.managers = [];

    $scope.RefreshManagerList = async function(){
        var response = await App.getStoreManagers();
        $scope.managers = response;
    };

    $scope.Setup = async function(){
        await App.start();
        await $scope.RefreshManagerList();
    };

    $scope.Setup();
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<header>
    <h1>Administrator Panel</h1>
</header>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Store Manager List</h3>

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="manager in managers">
            {{manager}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What is expected to happen is that when $scope.managers is set to response, the list should be rendered in the HTML page.

### EDIT:

Tried doing this also doesn't work. Console.log still gives the expected object to be displayed in the list. If I interact with the page in the slightest way, the list automatically loads:

```
app.controller("administratorController", function ($scope){
    $scope.managers = {content: null};

    $scope.RefreshManagerList = function(){
        App.getStoreManagers().then(function(response){
            $scope.managers.content = response;
            console.log($scope.managers.content);
        });
    };

    $scope.Setup = function(){
        App.start().then(function(){
            $scope.RefreshManagerList();
        });
    };

    $scope.Setup();
});
```

Comment: How/Where is `$scope.managers` modified?

Comment: And where is `$scope.RefreshManagerList` defined?

Comment: I don't see a code, where managers is getting filled, show some code of `App.start` and  `RefreshManagerList` method.

Comment: @PrerakSola and edited the post. Sorry my mistake for copying incorrect code.

Comment: I'm wondering if using `async` functions has anything to do with it. Could you try regular promises? Also, adding a plunker would be helpful

Comment: @MichaelKucinski I made an example using async/await and it works. It must be something else. https://codepen.io/FederalCircle/pen/yZRmJd

Comment: Updated the post. @MichaelKucinski still doesn't work.

Comment: @RyanFalzon - It's because `App` isn't an Angular component, and thus doesn't trigger a digest cycle. You said interacting with the page updates the page, in other words, once a digest cycle is triggered it all works. You can wrap your assignment call in a `$timeout` as a hack to get by.

Comment: @AlysonMaia placed $scope.digest after updating $scope.managers and still does not work. However I tried something else. I placed a button in the HTML which calls the function RefreshManagerList. When pressed the list updates and gets cleared immediately.

Comment: @tymeJV tried your approach but still nothing.

Comment: @RyanFalzon Have you ever used Angular Batarang plugin for Chrome? It helps to debug angular's scope via DevTools. It may help. A '$scope' tab will be added to the window with css styles when you inspect an element. [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)

Comment: `getStoreManagers` method using `Promise` API or `$q` promise?